# Python: open "chrome://" urls?

Tags: python, google-chrome, url, browser

I am trying to open the Chrome extension page ("chrome://extensions/") in Chrome as the last step of a local script (so I can finally reload an extension there).
Unfortunately I am failing with this. :-(

-> Python 2.7 for win 8.1 x64

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.get().open("chrome://extensions/")
```

This with Chrome as standard browser only results in windows telling me not knowing how to handle this:
[image]

And when I call Chrome directly via...

```
webbrowser.get("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s").open_new_tab("chrome://extensions/"))
```

... or ...

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen([r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe', 'chrome://extensions/']).wait()
```

... or when I try to open the URL via windows run dialog ...

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "chrome://extensions/"
```

... it always just opens a new window with the New Tab page, while a HTTP(S) URL opens these calls correctly.

Has anyone an idea how to open this chrome-specific page?

Comment: It sounds to me (from your second attempt) like Chrome deliberately prevents it.

Comment: This was my thought, too. But maybe someone knows something.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that by default accessing/passing chrome url's is disabled/sandboxed outside of chrome, but there are cli switches that can be passed to chrome that you can use to change this??

[List of Chrome switches here](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

[Extension code docs](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/extensions/common/switches.cc&q=kExtensionsOnChromeURLs&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=56), this might help you if all you are trying to do is reload an extension. Instead of doing it through the chrome:// URI

Comment: Thx, I was also thinking about a possible solution via the flags and specifically the "Extensions on chrome:// URLs" flag. However, this seems only to affect extensions. Therefore I'd have to write an extension, what I am currently not intending to do, though. :-) 
At least not yet.

I was skimming through the flags in your provided list, but could not really find anything that might be helpful for a simple solution.